# Is there an AngularJS scaffold/generator other than Yeoman/Yo?

Tags: angularjs, generator

As I've heard others experience, the Yeoman scaffold/generator doesn't seem to be working on my machine (Windows 10).  It was working a couple months ago.  Now, though the commands run, I get a couple errors and no files are produced.  Or, on another machine, the "yo" command does not even get recognized after following all instructions on the yeoman website.  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling.  Nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Angular2 has its own angular-cli https://cli.angular.io/